Does a smart group that has been created through several steps retain final criteria even when preceding smart groups are deleted?
We will often create smart groups in several steps to create a mailing list using the Advanced Search. For example, Search 1 may produce a list of all schools in a given area which we save as Smart Group 1. An advanced search of that smart group may lead to a list of all teachers at that school (Smart Group 2) and search 3 may produce a list of all headteachers from the list of teachers at those schools which might be the mailing list we ultimately needed - Smart Group 3. If we then go ahead and delete the Smart Groups 1 and 2 as we no longer 'need' them and say a new headteacher is appointed at one of the schools in question and we update the contact database accordingly, will that headteacher be automatically added into that Smart Group 3 or not and is this dependent on whether or not we deleted those intermediate smart groups 1 and 2?
Thanks

No it will still need the original groups to be present.

As @demerit says, you need the intermediate groups.
You might want to look at creating your smart groups using SearchKit.  It has more powerful searching options so you may be able to create the end result you want without needing the intermediate groups.
